# Is it worth finishing Assassin's Creed 1 before playing 2?

Tags: assassins-creed, assassins-creed-2

How much of the storyline carries over to the second version? I'm considering skipping to AC2 since I've heard its quite a bit more varied and generally a better game.

AC1 was fun in the beginning but now I get the feeling I'm just repeating the same things.

Comment: For those who prefer to watch AC 1 cut scenes and important moments check out this game play movie [Assassin's creed the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub9JUDS_6i8)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although you *can* play and enjoy it, AC2 is a direct sequel to AC1, so I'd suggest you play the first one to fully grasp the whole story.
The final part of the game is very entertaining and made it worth for me to play thorugh the repetitive parts.

AC3 will be the final part in the trilogy, completing it like one big game.

Comment: Thanks all for your opinions. I'm going to accept Juan's answer since the most fact based part of my question (nl. storyline carries over to the second one) was first answered by him. I think. :) Anyway, next thing I'm going to do is check how far I've played it already and decide based on that.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to invest that much time in AC1, I don't think you'd miss too much if you just [read the plot summary on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed#Plot) and [watch the ending on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8WEQ8y_WqY&feature=related). AC2 was an improvement over the original in pretty much every aspect (particularly storytelling) and I don't think you'd be lost.

Comment: Im playing through AC2 right now and after reading the plot summery, I still don't feel like I've really missed anything by not playing AC1

Answer (score 10):

I played AC2 without playing AC1, and I didn't feel like I was missing out on anything.

The main part of the game's story after all, is the section in the past, and the AC2 past sections take place in a different time period to those in AC1.

The "modern day" part does make a few back references, but these are mostly self explanatory.

Comment: I did the same thing (never finished AC1, but played AC2). If you aren't going to play the first one, I would recommend reading a synopsis of the plot to catch up. While AC2 does stand alone, it will make much more sense if you know what happened in the first game.

Comment: I also played AC2 without playing AC1 at all (I was put off by all the talk of repetitive gameplay), I found just reading the AC1 Wikipedia entry was good enough.

Answer (score 7):

You can never go back.

AC1 is not a bad game on its own, but if you think you ever want to finish it in the future I implore you not to start the second one.  The second one, like others have mentioned, smoothed out the rough parts and made AC2 a much more enjoyable experience.  Unfortunately that makes it sound like AC1 is crud.  Of course it isn't, if it was AC2 never would have made it to market.

If you play AC2, if you even *watch* somebody else play AC2 your enjoyment of AC1 will be lessened and you will find playing it to be a slog through the slow parts.

If you are the type of person who likes playing a game through, don't do AC2 first.  If you're not, skip AC1.

There's also a DS game, which I understand is a prequel to AC1 but I've never played it.

Answer (score 2):

You have no reason to play a game you are not enjoying. I played through both games and AC2 is a much improved sequel in every way. That's not to say AC is bad, I really enjoyed it. But if you are not enjoying it, don't play it. Read a summary of the AC1 story, see the cinematics on YouTube and play Assassin's Creed 2.